# SalesforceR: Enable PKChunking for SalesForce Bulk Query in R

Tags: r, salesforce, chunking

I am attempting to query a large table (30M records) from Salesforce to R using the SalesforceR package, and hope to do so without splitting up into many queries.

The following query (names changed for security/readability) succeeds, if I limit the records:

`OrderItemsSF <- sf_query_bulk("SELECT Id,Order,Product,Quantity FROM OrderItems LIMIT 1000000",object_name = "OrderItems", api_type = "Bulk 1.0", verbose = TRUE, max_attempts = 1000)`

This query fails ("Error: column name 'result' must not be duplicated") whenever it takes longer than 10 minutes, which fits with SF's documentation saying bulk queries retry after 10 minutes (see link 1 at bottom).  I believe the answer is to enable PKChunking to automatically separate my query into smaller batches, but I am having trouble finding a working syntax for this.

I have tried the following:

`` OrderItemsSF <- sf_query_bulk("SELECT Id,Order,Product,Quantity FROM OrderItems LIMIT 1000000",object_name = "OrderItems", api_type = "Bulk 1.0", verbose = TRUE, max_attempts = 1000, control = sf_control(PKChunkingHeader = list(`Sforce-Enable-PKChunking`= TRUE))) ``

This results in the error "Error in catch_errors(httr_response) : 
ClientInputError: Sforce-Enable-PkChunking doesn't have a valid value. The same error results from using FALSE, and according to the documentation (see link 2 at bottom), FALSE is the default for this parameter, so that doesn't make sense!

Other syntax attempts, like the one below, succeed on queries under 10 minutes and fail over 10 minutes, suggesting that R is ignoring this text and not actually PKChunking:

`` OrderItemsSF <- sf_query_bulk("SELECT Id,Order,Product,Quantity FROM OrderItems LIMIT 1000000",object_name = "OrderItems", api_type = "Bulk 1.0", verbose = TRUE, max_attempts = 1000, control = list(`Sforce-Enable-PKChunking`= TRUE)) ``

I'm at a loss for what seems like a simple syntax issue, and can't find any specific examples online of PKChunking in a SalesforceR query, despite the documentation saying this can be done.  I'd greatly appreciate some guidance here.

Link 1: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_bulk_query_processing.htm

Link 2: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/salesforcer/salesforcer.pdf#Rfn.sf.Rul.control

Answer (score 0):

The error listed above was a bug that exists in [{salesforcer}](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=salesforcer) v0.1.4 and below. As of v0.2.0, the issue has been resolved and you can execute a bulk query with PKChunking enabled like this:

```r
# install.packages('salesforcer')
library(salesforcer)

# authenticate using username, password, and security token ...
sf_auth(username = "test@gmail.com", 
        password = "{PASSWORD_HERE}",
        security_token = "{SECURITY_TOKEN_HERE}")

# ... or using OAuth 2.0 authentication
sf_auth()

# execute the query
contacts <- sf_query("SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact Limit 10000", 
                     object_name = "Contact", 
                     api_type = "Bulk 1.0",
                     PKChunkingHeader = list(`Sforce-Enable-PKChunking` = TRUE),
                     # alternatively you can turn on using specific chunking options like this ...
                     # PKChunkingHeader = list(`chunkSize` = 500),
                     interval_seconds = 10,
                     max_attempts = 200)
contacts
#> # A tibble: 383 x 2
#>    Id                 Name                           
#>    <chr>              <chr>                                     
#> 1 0033s000012NdFhAAK John Doe
#> 2 0033s000012NkzwAAC Jane Doe
#> 3 0033s000012NkzxAAC Jane Doe
#> 4 0033s000012NkzyAAC Jane Doe
#> 5 0033s000012NkzzAAC Jane Doe
#> # … with 378 more rows
```